# Kafka standalone error: WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 0 (kafka.network.Processor)

Tags: connection, apache-kafka

I install kafka on a standalone server and try to stream data to mongodb.
when start kafka service, bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
I had a warning: 
WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which                                                                         there is no open connection, connection id 0 (kafka.network.Processor)

Even though, there is no problem for data entered at producer and displayed at consumer.

but I think this cause the data write to mongodb. I have no data write to mongodb after start data streaming.

anyone can help with this issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you solved the above-mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //processor.sendResponse
  protected[network] def sendResponse(response: RequestChannel.Response) {
    trace(s"Socket server received response to send, registering for write and sending data: $response")
    val channel = selector.channel(response.responseSend.destination)
    // `channel` can be null if the selector closed the connection because it was idle for too long
    if (channel == null) {
      warn(s"Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id $id")
      response.request.updateRequestMetrics()
    }
    else {
      selector.send(response.responseSend)
      inflightResponses += (response.request.connectionId -> response)
    }
```

so, channel was closed by the selector because it was idle too long

Comment: We're experiencing timeouts on the producer side and for respective timeout on the producer side we see the "Attempting..." log message for relevant IP in kafka log file on the server. Does this mean default timeout connections.max.idle.ms  expired and server closed the channel? What is the standard way around? Is it enough if a producer reconnects?